Issue with attachments when resending an e-mail (that belongs to a Case) via Apex
I have an Apex batch job that periodically resends mails that belong to Cases. It creates a SingleEmailMessage, copies all relevant fields from the previous, most recently sent, EmailMessage and sends it.
If I look at the Case and its e-mails in Salesforce, it looks perfect. I click on each e-mail in the related list, and it looks just how it should look, including inline images.
However, on the receiving end, all inline images are the infamous X symbols. I have tried several e-mail clients, but none of them show the inline images.
If - in the Case in Salesforce - I personally reply to an e-mail that has inline images, the receiver sees these inline images.
So the SingleEmailMessage is missing something. I googled this and more people have problems with this. What I don't understand is that when I inspect the inline images in Salesforce, in the browser, they all point to the same image. But somehow the e-mails that are manually sent are received correctly, but those sent via Apex not. Even though they look the same in Salesforce.
Update: I downloaded the HTML bodies for the e-mails that I sent manually and that were sent by Apex. Both have the exact same line for the inline image:
<img alt="XYZ" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xxxxxxxxxxxx?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER" style="max-width: 1116.17578125px" title="XYZ"/>

The path /sfc/servlet... makes sense on a Salesforce site, but I would understand why an e-mail client doesn't know how to load this. I guess the manually sent e-mail has some attribute that tells an e-mail client on which site to find the inline images.
I looked at the EmailMessage fields for both e-mails, especially at something like 'IsExternallyVisible', but I cannot see any differences that might explain what I am (not) seeing.
My code:
for (EmailMessage em : scope) {
    String subject = StringUtils.emptyIfNull(em.Subject);
    if (! subject.startsWith(REMINDER_SUBJECT_BEGIN)) {
        subject = REMINDER_SUBJECT_BEGIN + subject;
    }
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setInReplyTo(em.MessageIdentifier);
    mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>{ em.ToAddress });
    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(emailAddressId);
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setHtmlBody(StringUtils.emptyIfNull(em.HtmlBody));
    mail.setPlainTextBody(StringUtils.emptyIfNull(em.TextBody));
    mail.setWhatId(em.ParentId);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    mailsToSend.add(mail);
}

Messaging.SendEmailResult[] mailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(mailsToSend, true);


are the inline images from inside rich text Case.xxx__c fields?

@cropredy No, they are inside the e-mail messages (bodies).

Would you not send the SingleEmailMessage with an EmailFileAttachment that sets inline=true? (Just guessing.)

@FelixvanHove No, the attachments must be accessed via ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink.

Aren't the inline images held as ContentDocuments even if the initial email was sent manually?

@FelixvanHove I updated the question with the part of the e-mail HTML body that shows/should show an inline image.

Instead of ContentDocument, did you consider ContentAsset?  These will render just fine in emails

@SanderdeJong given you downloaded both email HTML bodies and the URLs are exactly the same, yet one email client displays the images and the other refuses - how exactly are you viewing the emails?
Are you sending the email and then accessing them in the same browser that you have salesforce logged in? Because I've had it in the past where my email client would render the images in emails received from Salesforce because I had the Salesforce token in browser.
Ideally testing 2 emails (manual + apex) sent to same email address, but email client in separate browser (or device). Let me know pls

@cropredy I haven't, because the inline images are ContentDocuments by default. I will look into this.

@vio I have used the Outlook Windows app and the GMail Android app. Both exhibit the same behavior, viz. the images in manually sent e-mails are rendered, whereas those in automatically sent e-mails are not.

Have you tried comparing the email headers?  Gmail's web client has a "show original" option in the "stacked dots" menu for an email which shows the full raw email content, including email headers and each mime content section.

So, just copying the e-mail bodies obviously isn't enough. You also have to attach the images, using code similar to this:
    if (em.ContentDocumentIds?.size() > 0) {
        mail.setEntityAttachments(contentVersionIdsFrom(em.ContentDocumentIds));
    }

where the contentVersionIdsFrom method looks like this:
    List<Id> contentVersionIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Id cdId : contentDocumentIds) {
        Id cvId = mapFromContentDocumentIdToContentVersionId.get(cdId);
        if (cvId != null) {
            contentVersionIds.add(cvId);
        }
    }
    return contentVersionIds;

where mapFromContentDocumentIdToContentVersionId has been filled with what its name suggests.
This will actually solve only half of the problem. The images are now being sent by the Apex code, but, if they are inline images, they will not be displayed inline. You will see things like the literal text image001 in the message, as well as an attachment called image001.
Dealing with inline images is another issue (look here for example), but it's another question, so I will not deal with it here.
